# Parsing a File in Python on stdout

Tags: python

I am New to python and need help in parsing a file. My file is as below

```
 NODEPL2
 traffic-3.1.38 NOT_EQUAL_TO traffic-3.1.40-1912261131_0530e.noarch

 NODEPL2
 customization-3.1.56 NOT_EQUAL_TO customization-3.1.59.2-2002030347_75011c.noarch

 TestOT1
 osmo-1.0.44 EQUAL_TO osmo-1.0.44-1911120419_1378a.noarch

 TestOT1
 otam-1.0.44 EQUAL_TO otam-1.0.44-1911120419_1378a.noarch
```

My code to parse is as follows:

```
import os

f = open("/tmp/out.txt","r")
lines = f.read().splitlines()

notequalto = open("notequal.txt","w")
equalto = open("equalto.txt","w")

for id1,line1 in enumerate(lines):
    if "NOT_EQUAL_TO" in line1:
        notequalto.write(lines[id1-1])
        notequalto.write('\n')
        notequalto.write(line1)
        notequalto.write('\n\n')
for id2,line2 in enumerate(lines):
    if "EQUAL_TO" in line2:
        equalto.write(lines[id2-1])
        equalto.write('\n')
        equalto.write(line2)
        equalto.write('\n\n')

f.close()
notequalto.close()
equalto.close()
```

I want my O/p as below:

```
NODEPL2

 traffic-3.1.38 NOT_EQUAL_TO traffic-3.1.40-1912261131_0530e.noarch

 customization-3.1.56 NOT_EQUAL_TO customization-3.1.59.2-2002030347_75011c.noarch

 TestOT1

 osmo-1.0.44 EQUAL_TO osmo-1.0.44-1911120419_1378a.noarch

 otam-1.0.44 EQUAL_TO otam-1.0.44-1911120419_1378a.noarch
```

Comment: Your code writes two files, nothing on stdout. Are you happy with the file writes but also want stdout? I see NODEPL2 and TestOT1, are there lots of other names like this?

Comment: Hi @tdelaney,Yes you are right , there are around 1000 lot others name like this. I am happy to write it on the files, its ok if not seen on stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re` module. I'll consider the lines that contains **NODEPL2** and **TestOT1** as being the header. The lines right below the header I'll consider as being the content.

1. Use a Context Manager to work with files, ie `with` keyword.

```py
with open('/tmp/out.txt') as f:
    # work with the file here with operations such as f.readlines()
```

2. Note that the header lines have a pattern: they are not empty (they have more than one character) and are made up of characters that are not considered white space. The `re` module has a symbol for this type of pattern: `^\S+$`. Also note that the lines of content also have a pattern: they are separated by spaces between three character sets that are not empty. The `re` symbol for this type of pattern is `^(?:.+)? (?:.+)? (?:.+)?$`. You can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```py
with open('/tmp/out.txt') as f:
    header_pattern = re.compile(r'^\S+$')
    content_pattern = re.compile(r'^(?:.*)? (?:.*)? (?:.*)?$')

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()

        if header_pattern.match(line):
            print('HEADER', line)
        elif content_pattern.match(line):
            print('CONTENT', line)
```

If you run the above code, you'll see the following output:

```
HEADER NODEPL2
CONTENT traffic-3.1.38 NOT_EQUAL_TO traffic-3.1.40-1912261131_0530e.noarch
HEADER NODEPL2
CONTENT customization-3.1.56 NOT_EQUAL_TO customization-3.1.59.2-2002030347_75011c.noarch
HEADER TestOT1
CONTENT osmo-1.0.44 EQUAL_TO osmo-1.0.44-1911120419_1378a.noarch
HEADER TestOT1
CONTENT otam-1.0.44 EQUAL_TO otam-1.0.44-1911120419_1378a.noarch
```

Now that you know how to get the lines and distinguish between header and content, you can use a dictionary to associate a header with its respective content and, after reading the file, write the dictionary contents in two different files.

Comment: Thanks @Enzo, for the help, But i need my o/p as i have described in my question for an audit purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are happy with the file output but want to group lines by id to write to stdout. A dictionary is a great tool for that - use it to create a mapping from each id to a list of lines associated with that id. `collections.defaultdict` does some of the bookkeeping for you so that you can skip testing whether an id/list pair already exists before doing the append.

**EDIT**

Since you want group records by id on stdout and the target files, I moved the file writes out of the main categorization loop. I also wrote functions to do the output as the action is the same for both id maps.

```
import collections
import sys

def _print_multiple(*args, files=[]):
    """Call `print` for each file object in files"""
    for f in files:
        print(*args, file=f)

def _output_values(id_map, files=[]):
    """Write id/values to given files"""
    for id_, values in id_map.items():
        _print_multiple(id_, files=files)
        for value in values:
            _print_multiple(value, files=files)
        _print_multiple(files=files)

# categorize items
equalto_id_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
notequalto_id_map = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open("/tmp/out.txt") as f:
    for line in (l.strip() for l in f):
        if "NOT_EQUAL_TO" in line:
            notequalto_id_map[prev].append(line)
        elif "EQUAL_TO" in line:
            equalto_id_map[prev].append(line)
        else:
            prev = line

# write categories to file and stdout
with open("notequal.txt","w") as notequalto:
    _output_values(notequalto_id_map, files=[sys.stdout, notequalto])

with open("equalto.txt","w") as equalto:
    _output_values(equalto_id_map, files=[sys.stdout, equalto])
```

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney, this pretty good  Appreciate your help, i get my accurate results on STDOUT., As iam new to Python, i am not able to store the std o/p to files. Same STD o/p in my "equalto.txt" and notequalto.txt". If you can help here as well that woudl be great.

Comment: @Rakesh - I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want the same id/values grouping in the two files as in stdout? Do you want to redirect stdout to a third file?

Comment: Hi @Tdelaney, i want the same id/value grouping on two files as in stdout. i.e  id/value of "equalto" goes to equalto.txt and id/value of "notequalto" goes to notequalto.txt

Comment: Hi @tdelaney, i want the same id/value grouping on two files as in stdout. i.e id/value of "equalto" goes to equalto.txt and id/value of "notequalto" goes to notequalto.txt

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot and finally found my solution i used the "flag" option and Bingo i could get desired results in the o/p files as desired.

```
if __name__== "__main__":
    IN_FILE = "/tmp/out.txt"
    OUT_FILE_NOT_EQUALTO = "/tmp/notequal.txt"
    OUT_FILE_EQUALTO = "/tmp/equalto.txt"
    OUT_FILE_NOT_FOUND = "/tmp/notfound.txt"
    nodelist = getListOfNodes(IN_FILE)
    nodes_set = set(nodelist)
    nodes_list = list(nodes_set)
 for item in nodes_list:
        rpmComment_list = getRpmComment(IN_FILE,item)
        #print(item,rpmComment_list)

        with open(OUT_FILE_NOT_EQUALTO,"a") as notequalto, open(OUT_FILE_EQUALTO,"a") as equalto, open(OUT_FILE_NOT_FOUND,"a") as notfound:
            not_equal_present_flag = 0
            equal_to_present_flag = 0
            not_found_present_flag = 0
            for item1 in rpmComment_list:
                if "NOT_EQUAL_TO" in item1:
                    if not_equal_present_flag == 0:
                        notequalto.write(item+"\n")
                        notequalto.write(item1+"\n")
                        not_equal_present_flag = 1
                    elif not_equal_present_flag == 1:
                        notequalto.write(item1+"\n")
                if "IDENTICAL_WITH" in item1:
                    if equal_to_present_flag == 0:
                        equalto.write(item+"\n")
                        equalto.write(item1+"\n")
                        equal_to_present_flag = 1
                    elif equal_to_present_flag == 1:
                        equalto.write(item1+"\n")
                if "NOT_FOUND" in item1:
                    if not_found_present_flag == 0:
                        notfound.write(item+"\n")
                        notfound.write(item1+"\n")
                        not_found_present_flag = 1
                    elif not_found_present_flag == 1:
                        notfound.write(item1+"\n")

            if not_equal_present_flag == 1:
                notequalto.write("\n")
            if equal_to_present_flag == 1:
                equalto.write("\n")
            if not_found_present_flag == 1:
                notfound.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the modules `re` and `collections.defaultdict`:

```
data = """
 NODEPL2
 traffic-3.1.38 NOT_EQUAL_TO traffic-3.1.40-1912261131_0530e.noarch

 NODEPL2
 customization-3.1.56 NOT_EQUAL_TO customization-3.1.59.2-2002030347_75011c.noarch

 TestOT1
 osmo-1.0.44 EQUAL_TO osmo-1.0.44-1911120419_1378a.noarch

 TestOT1
 otam-1.0.44 EQUAL_TO otam-1.0.44-1911120419_1378a.noarch
"""

import re
from collections import defaultdict

# the regex
rx = re.compile(r"""
    ^
    \s*(?P<key>\w+)\n
    \s*(?P<value>.+)
""", re.X | re.M)

result = defaultdict(list)

for m in rx.finditer(data):
    result[m.group('key')].append(m.group('value'))

output = "\n".join(line
                   for key, values in result.items()
                   for line in ["{}\n {}".format(key, "\n ".join(values))])
print(output)
```

Which yields

```
TestOT1
 osmo-1.0.44 EQUAL_TO osmo-1.0.44-1911120419_1378a.noarch
 otam-1.0.44 EQUAL_TO otam-1.0.44-1911120419_1378a.noarch
NODEPL2
 traffic-3.1.38 NOT_EQUAL_TO traffic-3.1.40-1912261131_0530e.noarch
 customization-3.1.56 NOT_EQUAL_TO customization-3.1.59.2-2002030347_75011c.noarch
```

See [**a demo for the expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/6od9Gj/1).